# Prevent Enter key from taking me inside a for loop

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, editor

When I used the Visual Studio 2013 editor for writing in C#, pressing the enter key on the keyboard would simply insert a newline at the current cursor position and take me to the next line, which is what I want.

I've installed Visual Studio 2015 and it seems that now if I have recently created a for loop (with the automatically-generated snippet), and moved the cursor to somewhere in the vicinity, then pressing enter will take me several lines forward and into the for loop.

This is completely unintuitive and driving me crazy. How can I make it stop doing that? I thought for sure I wasn't the only one with this problem, but multiple attempts to search for the solution failed, as did browsing Tools > Options > Text Editor > C#.

Answer (score 0):

I've not seen this yet, but I guess I can understand it. After you move the cursor and before you hit enter, maybe pressing `ESCAPE` to stop it from auto generating the for-block. It sounds like you got the editor to the point where its ready to auto generate that bad boy for you, and it's still waiting for the go ahead even after you move the cursor. So when you hit the `ENTER` key, it assumes you really just wanted to generate the for block, in which it gladly moves the cursor back down to where it wants it to be. Microsoft making things worse by trying to make them better.. once again.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not it. This is happening after the block was already generated. See more details in my comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35349860/prevent-enter-key-from-taking-me-inside-a-for-loop/35350277#comment58408960_35350277.

Answer (score 0):

The way code snippets work in Visual Studio 2015 is slightly different compared to you may be used to. As explained in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165392.aspx):

> **Snippets can contain replacement parameters, which** are placeholders that **you must replace** to fit the precise code you are writing. In the previous example true is a replacement parameter, which you would replace with the appropriate condition. The replacement you make is repeated for every instance of the same replacement parameter in the snippet.
>
> For example, in Visual Basic there is a code snippet that inserts a property. Click Insert Snippet on the context menu of the code window, then Code Patterns, then Properties, Procedures, Events, then Define a property. The following code is inserted:
>
> `Private newPropertyValue As String
>   Public Property NewProperty() As String
>       Get
>           Return newPropertyValue
>       End Get
>       Set(ByVal value As String)
>           newPropertyValue = value
>       End Set
>   End Property`
>
> If you change `newPropertyValue` to `m_property`, then every instance of `newPropertyValue` is changed. If you change `String` to `Int` in the property declaration, then the value in the set method is also changed to  `Int`.

Comment: This seems related but it's not precisely it. Basically my flow is: 1. I type "for TAB TAB", a snippet is generated. 2. There are placeholders bolded in yellow, I replace them with appropriate values. 3. I press up a few times and get to a different line. The placeholder positions are still bolded. 4. I press enter. I'm teleported inside the for body, and the placeholders are no longer bolded. So this behavior happens after I have already duly substituted values for the placeholders.

Comment: @MeniRosenfeld Yes but that's the default beaviour in my opinion because you are supposed to "exit the replacement mode" by pressing enter. Navigating somewhere else does not exit the "replacement mode".

Comment: It should, IMO. Any way to change this behavior?